# Cannot format code in in vim with %= ... result is E488: Trailing characters

Tags: vim, groovy, format, indentation

I am trying to format some groovy code in vim

Firstly I the command type ":set smartindent"

... then I type the command ":=%"

and the error I get is the following:

E488: Trailing characters

Here is the code I am trying to format:

```
import groovy.util.GroovyTestCase

class MyTest extends GroovyTestCase {

        void testSomething() {
                assert 1 == 1
    assert 2 + 2 == 4 : "We're in trouble, arithmetic is broken"
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong???
Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why the colon? `=` is a normal-mode command. The `:=` ex command is for printing the number of lines in your buffer (or specified range), and will accept some flags only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `:=%` is supposed to work because `%` is not a motion.

If you want to format the whole file, you should rather use `gg=G`

Otherwise, select an area and use `=`, for example `vi}=`, you don't have to enter command mode to reformat (Command mode is when you are entering `:`)

Comment: I tried ":=1G" and got the same error. Using gg=G returns "10 lines indented" but does not actually indent anything.Using visual mode to select the  text and then pressing "=" returns "10 lines indented" but no actual indent takes place.

Comment: The issue is SEMICOLONS. As soon as I add semicolons to my code the formatting works fine. This is a little odd as I was under the impression that setting "smartindent" formatted on code the basis of where the curly braces "{}" are, not where the semicolons ";" are. What is going on??

Comment: I think the default vim indent rules are based on C. So it is probably why without ;, it is not able to do much.

Comment: As far as I know, syntax files are only used to highlight part of your code in different colours, but don't define anything regarding to indentation. See `:help indent.txt` for more information. You need an `indent script`for groovy, like this one : http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2961 . It will define the correct `indentexpr` for Groovy.

Comment: Sorry ... here is the link to the indent file. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2961

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the commands ...

```
vG$=
```